# I have one stack item, I want to exit the application by double clicking back pressed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

if I have one stack item, I want to exit the application by double clicking back pressed,  how will I know when I will have one item on stack? 
My code in override method onBackPressed

if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {

```
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()==1){
        moveTaskToBack(false);
    }
    else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, you can follow what I comment in the code.

```
private static final long DURATION_BETWEEN_BACK_PRESS = 1000;
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private boolean isBackButtonPressed = false;
private final Runnable resetIsBackButtonPressed = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        isBackButtonPressed = false;
    }
};

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    int backStackEntryCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (backStackEntryCount == 0) {
        // There is no item in back stack. This happens when you do not add any fragment to activity.
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    if (backStackEntryCount > 1) {
        // The back stack has more than one item, just pop top item from the stack.
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
        return;
    }

    // The back stack has only one item left.
    if (!isBackButtonPressed) {
        // The first time back button pressed.
        isBackButtonPressed = true;

        // If users do not press back key second time in a given duration, then just reset back pressed status.
        handler.postDelayed(resetIsBackButtonPressed, DURATION_BETWEEN_BACK_PRESS);
    } else {
        // The second time back button pressed.
        handler.removeCallbacks(resetIsBackButtonPressed);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I meant,tkanks!